# Restriction to use DECLARE in a SQL view

Tags: sql, view

I have a sql query that I need to put into a view.  I have it working as a stored procedure but my requirement is for it to be a View. This means I cant declare dynamic SQL as I have done in my stored procedure.

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t.Data_Term) 
                    from [UD_FldValues] t
                    inner join Surgery p
                        on t.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id where t.Data_term!=''
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT Tran_Id,Section_Id,SubSection_Id,R_Id,Hospital_Id,Surgeon_Id,Procedure_ICD,Procedure_Details,DtSurgery_TimeIn,DtSurgery_TimeOut,Intra_oper_compl_Id, p.Discharge_Date,Discharge_Status_Id,Entered_By,Entered_Date,p.Status,p.Ud_Form_Id,p.Complication_ICD,p.Complication_Name, Procedure_Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select t.Tran_Id
                      , t.[R_Id]
                      , p.Ud_Form_Id
                      ,p.Procedure_Name
                      ,p.Section_Id
                      ,p.SubSection_Id
                      ,p.Hospital_Id
                      ,p.Surgeon_Id
                      ,p.Procedure_ICD
                      ,p.Procedure_Details
                      ,p.DtSurgery_TimeIn
                      ,p.DtSurgery_TimeOut
                      ,p.Intra_oper_compl_Id
                      ,p.Discharge_Date
                      ,p.Discharge_Status_Id
                      ,p.Entered_By,
                      p.Entered_Date
                      ,p.Status
                      ,p.Complication_ICD
                      ,p.[Complication_Name]
                      , case when (t.Data_Type=''Text'') THEN t.Text_Value Else Convert(varchar(MAx),Num_Value) END as txtvl
                      ,t.Data_term
                    from Surgery p 
                    left outer join [UD_FldValues] t
                        on t.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id and t.Tran_Id=p.Surgery_Id
                        left outer join UD_Formmap fm ON fm.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id 
                    where fm.module_id = 1

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(txtvl)
                for Data_Term in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec(@query)
```

Please help me find an alternate way, but not store procedures. I need it in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a view it needs to be a single select statement,

your @cols statement returns a list of columns, this is used twice within your main select statement. so replacing @cols in your main query with the query that populates this should work.

set @query  and then exec(@query) isnt necessary either so you just have to tidy up and make sure the right number of brackets are in place.

and it should look something like this.

```
 SELECT Tran_Id
,Section_Id
,SubSection_Id
,R_Id,Hospital_Id
,Surgeon_Id,Procedure_ICD
,Procedure_Details
,DtSurgery_TimeIn
,DtSurgery_TimeOut
,Intra_oper_compl_Id
,p.Discharge_Date
,Discharge_Status_Id
,Entered_By,Entered_Date
,p.Status,p.Ud_Form_Id
,p.Complication_ICD
,p.Complication_Name
,Procedure_Name,
 (select STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t.Data_Term) 
                      from [UD_FldValues] t
                      inner join Surgery p
                      on t.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id where t.Data_term!=''
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'');))
 from 
                     (
                    select t.Tran_Id
                          , t.[R_Id]
                          , p.Ud_Form_Id
                          ,p.Procedure_Name
                          ,p.Section_Id
                          ,p.SubSection_Id
                          ,p.Hospital_Id
                          ,p.Surgeon_Id
                          ,p.Procedure_ICD
                          ,p.Procedure_Details
                          ,p.DtSurgery_TimeIn
                          ,p.DtSurgery_TimeOut
                          ,p.Intra_oper_compl_Id
                          ,p.Discharge_Date
                          ,p.Discharge_Status_Id
                          ,p.Entered_By,
                          p.Entered_Date
                          ,p.Status
                          ,p.Complication_ICD
                          ,p.[Complication_Name]
                          , case when (t.Data_Type=''Text'') THEN t.Text_Value Else Convert(varchar(MAx),Num_Value) END as txtvl
                          ,t.Data_term
                        from Surgery p 
                        left outer join [UD_FldValues] t
                            on t.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id and t.Tran_Id=p.Surgery_Id
                            left outer join UD_Formmap fm ON fm.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id 
                        where fm.module_id = 1

                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    min(txtvl)
                        for Data_Term in ( 
select STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t.Data_Term) 
                            from [UD_FldValues] t
                            inner join Surgery p
                                on t.Ud_Form_Id = p.Ud_Form_Id where t.Data_term!=''
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'');)

 ) p
```

Comment: in the process of typing up the explanation, 2 downvotes is a little harsh

Comment: Explanation is good @pancho018 i am working on it brackets issues are there hope fully i ll be there wish me luck

Comment: The explanation is a start, but it still won't work. The **only** way to generate columns at run time is to use dynamic sql, which you can't use in a view.

Comment: The problem is the criteria for a downvote - "This answer is not useful" - it is unrelated to effort. I am a bit on the fence about it, because with the explanation now, it makes sense what you are trying to achieve, however, it still doesn't work, so doesn't answer the question, and is therefore not useful, so those that have downvoted are entirely justified in doing so. In referring to it as harsh, you may be taking it too personally, it is not an attack on you, just a reflection of the fact that the answer does not solve the problem.